# Facebook analytic export always return "SCHEDULED" when call check status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im new on getting with `facebook api`. When i try to use facebook analytic export API, i got `FBID` then I query status but it always return "`SCHEDULED`" status, on facebook api document, they said it will take about 1 -> 2 hours, but it waiting for about 3 days but it not change.
This is API link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export/

This is a example of request i made in today at 2017-10-09 04:10 UTC

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": "352212478559555",
            "start_ts": "2017-10-07T08:00:00+0000",
            "end_ts": "2017-10-07T09:00:00+0000",
            "status": "SCHEDULED",
            "column_names": [
             .....
         }
```

Anyone faced with this problem? i already searched on google but no luck :(

Comment: This problem have been resolved, problem is about facebook export system have delay time when process export requests.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to export app events data as the documentation states that it is getting deprecated in 1st Aug 2018?

Answer (score 1):

This problem have been resovled. I have sent support ticket to facebook and problem is facebook export system too busy and it have delay time.